# ERROR joining tables to select data from both tables

Tags: mysql, sql, select, left-join

I've been trying to find out how to do this certain SQL statement but to no avail as it keeps throwing back the same error, and the online documents weren't great help.

```
ERROR 1066: Not unique table/alias: 'users'
```

Essentially what I'm trying to do is make a leaderboard, the php and html are done for it, it's just the SQL statement to the database is the trouble. I am trying to select the *first name*, *last name*, max int for *points*, and the *id* from the table *users*, but **the id and points have to be matched to the equivalent ones in the *blog* table**.

so far my code is this:

```
SELECT users.fname, users.lname, MAX(points), users.id 
FROM users 
LEFT  JOIN blog ON users.id=blog.id 
               AND users.points=blog.points 
ORDER BY points DESC LIMIT 0 , 10
```

Is there any thing you can do to rectify the error?

Here is the schema for it: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/58e77/1

Comment: What errors are you having? I see an aggregate function (ie, `MAX`) but no `GROUP BY` keyword, which is required so I am left to assume this might be the error you are referring to?

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot to write in the error, silly me:

The error is: ERROR 1066: Not unique table/alias: 'users'

Comment: Can you provide the table structures? If you can do it on sqlfiddle.com, that would help even more.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0):

are you sure you don't have another table called users with a different schema? And you have no default schema selected?

you may need to do something like:

```
SELECT users.fname, users.lname, MAX(points), users.id 
FROM dbo.users <-------------------------------------------- SEE HERE
LEFT  JOIN blog ON users.id=blog.id 
               AND users.points=blog.points 
ORDER BY points DESC LIMIT 0 , 10
```

Comment: I made a database just for this specifically to test out, and only made the tables `users` and `blog`, it's a bugger of a nuisance honestly.